# How to merge columns of one file to another file in R?

Tags: r, merge

Suppose I have two files `df1.csv` and `df2.csv`:

```
   a b c
1  . . . 
2  . . .
3  . . .
```

and

```
   d e f
1  . . . 
2  . . .
3  . . .
```

How can I merge both `.csv` to be the following output?

```
   a b c d e f
1  . . . . . .
2  . . . . . .
3  . . . . . .
```

Comment: Try with `cbind(df1, df2)`  if it is just to append the columns, or else use `merge`

Comment: @akrun, I did not get the expected `3 x 6` output. I got a `3 x 4` output using `cbind()` and `9 x 4` output using `merge()`

Comment: *update* sorry for the confusion, `cbind()` did work. I must have used the wrong variable before that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akrun solution does work:

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L), b = c(2L, 2L, 2L), c = c(3L, 3L, 3L)),
                 .Names = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))


df2 <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L), b = c(2L, 2L, 2L), c = c(3L, 3L, 3L)),
                 .Names = c("d", "e", "f"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))

cbind(df1, df2)    

 a b c d e f
 1 2 3 1 2 3
 1 2 3 1 2 3
 1 2 3 1 2 3
```